# Building a React module: addComponentAsRefTo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, webpack, react-dom

I'm trying to build a React module and then use it in my main app, but upon using it I get:

> addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might
>   be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a
>   component\'s render method, or you have multiple copies of React
>   loaded.

Here is the webpack of my `AwesomeModule`:

```
const prodConfig = {
    entry: {
        'awesomeModule.js': './src/js/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: PATHS.distJs,
        filename: 'awesomeModule.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: 'AwesomeModule'
    },
    externals: {
        'react': 'React',
        'moment': 'moment',
        'lodash': 'lodash'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
                include: PATHS.src,
                loader: 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                include: PATHS.src,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
        }),
        new AssetsPlugin({
            filename: 'assets.json',
            path: PATHS.distJs,
            fullPath: false,
            prettyPrint: true
        }),
        envParamsPlugin
    ]
};
```

In my main app, I add it to `dependencies` in my `package.json`. Here is my webpack config for my `App`

```
const prodConfig = {
    entry: {
        'app.js': "./src/index.jsx"
    },
    output: {
        path: PATHS.distJs,
        filename: "app-[hash].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
                include: PATHS.src,
                loader: "babel"
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                include: PATHS.src,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
        }),
        new AssetsPlugin({
            filename: 'assets.json',
            path: PATHS.distJs,
            fullPath: false,
            prettyPrint: true
        }),
        envParamsPlugin
    ]
};
```

Where is my problem?